# JQuery stops working after navigating other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

On my rails application I am able to have a row  on a table clickable to a link by using the code:
app/assets/javascripts/custom.js:

```
var main = function() {
  $("#my_table tr").on('click', function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("link")
  });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="my_table">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-link= "<%= my_path(myobject) %>">
       <td><%= myobject.name %></td>
       <td><%= myobject.email %></td>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

However, after visiting a different page and getting back to the page with the table, the rows are no longer clickable. It only works if I refresh the browser. What do I need to do so that the functionality does not stop after switching pages?

Comment: use once live function

Comment: @navnit `$( "#my_table tr" ).one( "click", function() {` does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to turbo-links, I experienced many quarky Js errors using Turbolinks with Rails 5.

Try:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // your code
}
```

Instead of

```
 $(document).ready(main)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the `data-link="http://domain.com/path"` in your TR elements? You did not put how the TR looks like...

For a redirection, to simulate you click a link you can use:

```
window.location.href = $(this).data("link")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added the `data-link="path"` in the `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

I think what Navnit Mishra meant is not using`$( "#my_table tr" ).one( "click", function() {` as an event handler, but using

```
$( "#my_table tr" ).live( "click", function() {(your_event)})
```

to handle your event.
.live allow you to attach event handler for an element in class in the future as well.
The [details for .live in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is available on jquery site.